# How do I deserialize an array of enum using Json.Net?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json.net

I have a JSON like this:

```
[{ 
    "agencyId": "myCity",
    "road": {
    "note": "",
        "lat": "45.321",
        "lon": "12.21",
        "streetCode": "290",
        "street": "street1",
        "fromNumber": "",
        "toNumber": "",
        "fromIntersection": "",
        "toIntersection": ""
    },
    "changeTypes": ["PARKING_BLOCK", "ROAD_BLOCK"],
},]
```

and a class like this:

```
public class AlertRoad : BaseAlert
{
    [JsonProperty("agencyId")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public AgencyType AgencyId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("changeTypes")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ChangeType[] ChangeTypes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("road")]
    public Road RoadInfo { get; set; }
}
```

AgencyType is an enumeration, and deserializiation and serialization for AgencyId works.

ChangeType is another enumeration, but deserializiation and serialization for ChangeTypes doesn't work.
I assume the reason is that ChangeTypes is an array of enumeration values.

The question is: how can I deserialize/serialize ChangeTypes field, or in general an array of enumeration values?

I tried by defining my own field converter, called ChangeTypeConverter, and changing StrinEnumConverter to ChangeTypeConverter for ChangeTypes field, but in the ReadJson function the value of reader is null.

```
public class ChangeTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var val = reader.Value;
        //val is null?!?
        return val;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ChangeType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `StringEnumConverter` expects only a single enumeration value.  Because `ChangeTypes` is an array, you need to annotate the property a little differently to make it work.

Try this instead:

```
[JsonProperty("changeTypes", ItemConverterType=typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public ChangeType[] ChangeTypes { get; set; }
```

Comment: Instead of JsonProperty on the property, a cleaner approach is to **use StringEnumConverter attribute over enum itself**. I prefer it since my case I didn't want to have an alias to my property name and if we need to use ItemConverterType, then the only way is to use JsonProperty and unnecessary provide alias name.

Comment: What if it's a `DataMember` attribute?

Answer (score 18):

There is no need to write a custom JsonConverter for serializing/deserializing array of Enum.
Instead of decorating individual property within parent model, just decorate the Enum with a StringEnumConverter JsonConverter attribute.

For eg:-

Following Environment model has Shelter enum property and array of enum Shelter[]

```
public class Environment
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Shelter Shelter { get; set; }
    public Shelter[] Shelters { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Shelter
{
    Indoor,
    Outdoor
}
```

Output json:-

```
 {
   "name": "",
   "shelter": "Indoor",
    "shelters": [
       "Indoor",
       "Outdoor"
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Note it may not always be possible to decorate the enum directly with an attribute, e.g. if it is defined in a third-party library.  A good example is [`System.Windows.Media.Colors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Not sure why but, JsonConverter attribute did not work for an array of enums when declared in the class but it worked when declared right in the enum definition.